# WIX: define not working in my .wxs file

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to define myUpgrade code based on OS

```
<?if VersionNT=601?>
   <?define MyUpgradeCode="{GUIDFOR_WIN7}"?>
<?elseif VersionNT&gt;=602?>
 <?define MyUpgradeCode="{GUIDFOR_WIN8AND_LATER}"?>
<?endif?>
....
....
....
<Product Name="My Product"
            Id="*"
            UpgradeCode="$(var.MyUpgradeCode)"
            Version=""
            Language="1033"
            >
```

but its failing to evaluate.

```
 error CNDL0150: Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.MyUpgradeCode)'. [C:\
Users\abc\Installer.wixproj]
```

How can I configure 2 **upgradeCodes** based on to be installed Windows OS version?

Comment: We need to know what this is for - why do you need two upgrade codes? It does not sound like it is good design. Preprocessor variables are not runtime variables - they merely change the source file before it is sent to the compiler - they are nowhere to be found when you install the MSI - then you deal with **runtime variables** (and not **compile-time variables** which preprocessor variables are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a 64 bit machine then you need to use [VERSIONNT64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372497(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of the [VERSIONNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372495(v=vs.85).aspx) property.

May I ask why you are changing upgrade code based on the operating system? If you are just trying to avoid maintaining 2 different versions of the WXS file, why don't you just do conditional install instead? If there are specific components/features going to Win7 and Win8 why not not mark the components/features as conditional using the [Condition Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/condition.html)?

OR You can block the entire install based on the operating system as mentioned [HERE](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/block_install_on_os.html)

***Update***

```
    <?define MyUpgradeCode ?>

 <?if VersionNT=601?>
      <?define MyUpgradeCode="{BF23D7DA-FE7D-446A-8950-3B92DD40FED3}"?>
  <?elseif VersionNT&gt;=602?>
      <?define MyUpgradeCode="{3CA8F7F3-312B-4778-97CE-EE9B2C5453E6}"?>
  <?endif?>
```

Replace your WXS with the above code and it will work. You are first defining the variable and then setting it's value within the IF/ElseIF code.

Now one important thing to point out is that the IF/Else and all other conditional statements in WIX are evaluated at the build time. So it will be setting the upgrade property based on the OS version of the machine/server on which it is compiling not where it is deploying.

> The purpose of the conditional statement is to allow you to include or exclude a segment of xml at build time. If the expression evaluates to true, it will be included. If it evaluates to false, it will be ignored.

Read more about it here. [WIX PRE PROCESSOR](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html)

Comment: okay, can you add the installation logs here?Log syntax
msiexec /I mymsi.msi /l*v File.txt

Comment: I was testing this out, I see what is happening. It wont even compile as the variable is not evaluated at that point. Like I said, can you elaborate on why you need a separate GUID, its not a good idea for a single MSI to have multiple upgrade codes. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372375(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I think you should be using conditional elements and restricting what goes to Win7 vs win8 instead of changing the product code. Please let me know what you are trying to achieve and I might be able to help!

Comment: Thanks, its compilation failures so i cannot share logs. My question is why this cant done? I have checked few other wix projects, it has been used via .wxi files, defined in .wxi, so why we cannot use it .wxs file?

Comment: Updated the answer - please check.

Comment: Thanks Isaih. I have not checked because, if its making decision at compile time then its not making any sense to use <?define>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like You are defining Your variables outside the project node. I had the same error when I used the WiX Setup-Editor, which created all sorts of varible like in Your sample. Move defines to inside project node and then the answer above is correct.